# What is the role of SetPrivateDataValidationParameter with implicit data collection in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

What is the use of `SetPrivateDataValidationParameter` with implicit data collection in Hyperledger Fabric?
Implicit data collection is only for an individual Org, how using other Orgs in `SetPrivateDataValidationParameter` is useful?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that `SetPrivateDataValidationParameter` typically would not be used with implicit collections since the endorsement policy for an implicit collection is the corresponding organization.

`SetPrivateDataValidationParameter` is more useful for explicit collections where there could be multiple collection members and you want to set the endorsement policy for a certain key to a subset or a single organization within the collection membership.

However, there are use cases where `SetPrivateDataValidationParameter` could be used with implicit collections. For example consider a use case where auction status is held in an auctioneer's implicit private data collection. A seller may want their own peer and the auctioneer's peer to endorse a transaction for their keyed items. `SetPrivateDataValidationParameter` would be used to ensure that both orgs endorse future transactions on the key.

Comment: I observed that Org1 implicit collection a key/value can be overridden (SetPrivateState) by Org2 even though I  called SetPrivateDataValidationParameter with only Org1 MSP. I was expecting Org2 should not be able to change the data of the key because it is locked by Org1 but it does not happen.